# Mage_CatalogRule_Model_Action_Index_Refresh - what does this do in Magento 1.8?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, upgrade, magento-1.8

I recently upgraded a website running Magento CE 1.7.0.2 to 1.8.1.0

In 1.8.1.0 there is a class called

```
Mage_CatalogRule_Model_Action_Index_Refresh
```

The file is at app/code/core/Mage/CatalogRule/Model/Action/Index/Refresh.php. This doesn't exist in Magento 1.7.0.2

As usual there's very little in the way of code comments/documentation about what this actually does.

I had an error on my 1.8 website during saving/adding a product:

`SQLSTATE[21S01]: Insert value list does not match column list: 1136 Column count doesn't match value count at row 1`

Other people have reported a similar error after a 1.7 -> 1.8 upgrade, e.g. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/7728/reindex-price-issue-value-list-does-not-match-column-list

I narrowed this down by enabling SQL logging to a function in the new class mentioned above called _fillIndexData. Essentially this runs an SQL query which isn't valid against my database structure (and yes, I've run the Magento DB repair tool to see if the upgrade damaged anything, which it didn't). The SQL it generates even seems syntactically invalid.

I'd really like to understand better what this class is doing. I'm guessing it's something to do with catalog price rules and index management. I commented out the code inside _fillIndexData and the error above goes, and everything else seems to work as normal, although my testing so far has been a bit limited.

Comment: Hello @Andy F heve you found solution of this question? I have same issue if your issue resolve please put solution as answer

Comment: I'm afraid I didn't find a solution to this one.